# Installing ScientificPython as a dependency

Tags: python, installation, dependencies, package, setuptools

I am trying to list [ScientificPython](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ScientificPython/2.6) as a dependency in my `setup.py`. However, during the installation process, python seems to not find the package. What is wrong in my approach?

Here is my setup:

```
import setuptools
setuptools.setup(name = 'MyPack', version = '0.1', 
  description= 'Description.',
  author = 'Me',
  packages = setuptools.find_packages(),
  install_requires = ['ScientificPython'],
  dependency_links = ["https://sourcesup.cru.fr/frs/?group_id=180&release_id=1351#stable-releases-2-8-title-content"])
```

And this is the important part of the output when I run `python setup.py install`:

```
Processing dependencies for MyPack==0.1
Searching for ScientificPython
Reading https://sourcesup.cru.fr/frs/?group_id=180&release_id=1351#stable-releases-2-8-title-content
Download error: unknown url type: https -- Some packages may not be found!
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/ScientificPython/
Reading http://dirac.cnrs-orleans.fr/ScientificPython/
Reading http://starship.python.net/~hinsen/ScientificPython/
No local packages or download links found for ScientificPython
Best match: None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 22, in <module>
    dependency_links = ["https://sourcesup.cru.fr/frs/?group_id=180&release_id=1351#stable-releases-2-8-title-content"])
  File "/home/woltan/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/home/woltan/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/home/woltan/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/home/woltan/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/install.py", line 76, in run
  File "/home/woltan/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/install.py", line 104, in do_egg_install
  File "/home/woltan/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 211, in run
  File "/home/woltan/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 427, in easy_install
  File "/home/woltan/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 478, in install_item
  File "/home/woltan/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 519, in process_distribution
  File "/home/woltan/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 563, in resolve
  File "/home/woltan/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 799, in best_match
  File "/home/woltan/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 811, in obtain
  File "/home/woltan/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 434, in easy_install
  File "/home/woltan/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/setuptools/package_index.py", line 475, in fetch_distribution
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clone'
```

Maybe one issue is, that ScientificPython is somehow not accessible though [PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi), or at least not downloadable as `easy_install ScentificPython` will fail with `No local packages or download links found for ScentificPython`.

What do I need to do in order to install ScientificPython with setuptools?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not `scipy`?

Comment: @katrielalex For some reason, my former developers went for ScientificPython. So it would be a lot of work to rewrite the modules to use scipy instead. Plus, i am not sure how hard/easy it is to install scipy especially with regard to the lapack bindings...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is specifically that its trying to make an http connection to a https site. From what I can tell setuptools does not support connections to https. You're going to have to use another method for getting those packages.

My recommendation, if you want to use setuptools, is that you detail in the README for the file that they have to download that dependency and install it and then have the dependency in the setuptools that fails to the install if they don't have it.

Comment: Thats assuming they don't have a URL that without HTTPS. Them having a unencrypted HTTP destination with the files would be the simplest solution to the problem that would allow you to actually do the install the way you want it.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried putting the direct download link (`https://sourcesup.cru.fr/frs/download.php/2309/ScientificPython-2.8.tar.gz`) into the `dependency_links` rather than the html page as your script seems not to find the package and then tries to install `None`.

edit: just noticed: python apparently is not able to open https resources - try uploading it somewhere without https, using normal http

edit 2: Why don't you just put the whole ScientificPython folder into your distribution folder and make sure its setup.py (or whatever else you need to call) is called by your setup.py?

Comment: Do you know why ScientificPython cannot be installed via PyPI? And can you back up the https issue?

Comment: ScientificPython on PyPI only provides a link to its website where the download link only refers to the download page you already put into the `dependency_links`. I do not think python will try twice to download from the same page.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting similar error when installing MyProxyClient using `easy_install`:

> "Download error: unknown url type: https -- Some packages may not be found!"

and other errors about not finding openssl headers.

So installing `libssl-dev` (on Ubuntu) solved the problem for me!

Answer (score 1):

Python is unable to handle https protocol, install openssl-devel package and reinstall the python to fix this.